# Adding Resonance Component to a CMSIS DSP IIR Filter

Tags: filter, signal-processing, stm32, cmsis

I have a single bi-quad IIR filter setup on stm32f405rgt6 which I want to add a resonance component to. I want to be able to change this resonance on the fly as well. I did quite a bit of research but couldn't really find something that leads to a solution.

Solutions I have in mind:

- Perhaps it is possible to add a resonance component to my current
  formula to calculate the filter coefficients?
- Cascading IIR filters (which I couldn't find examples of and I don't
  know where to begin)

I calculate simply by using the calculation tables from books. My main focus is lowpass filter at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simply resolved my question by increasing the Q value above 1.